# NSURLSession Request returns 404 but works fine on Postman

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/airtime/send";
NSString *encodedString = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

NSDictionary *body = @{
                       ...
                       };
// convert the dictionary into json data
NSError *error;
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:&error];

// Create a post request with the json as a request body.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
request.HTTPBody = JSONData;

// create the task.
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Status code: %li", (long)((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode);
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);

        NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response Text: %@", responseText);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

The code returns "The requested resource could not be found" 404 as response but when I try this request in my REST client (Postman) it works fine.

Comment: check your URL is valid or not

Comment: how do i check the validity of a URL?

Comment: the URL is valid, i've checked that. I even tried a GET request against the endpoint, I get "HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: POST", which is correct. So POST is returning 404 somehow

Comment: I see that you are not using "https", did you configure Transport Security Exception for server url?

Comment: If he got a 404 response that means that its not a problem with ATS

Comment: I ran this code myself and got error code 400.

Answer (score 0):

Try a url with the URLWithString method

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.sandbox.africastalking.com/version1/airtime/send"];
```